# What does [allowDefinition] error message mean?

Tags: asp.net

I am getting this error when i run my web site.

```
allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.
```

But this web site run smoothly on my local machine as wel as i have another site with same hosting account run without any issue.Please help me to find out solution.

Comment: If a application has two web.config,Then this error might occur or if there is a folder present inside your website then also this problem may occur.

Comment: yes it has a 2 web.config files but in a different folders.Different folders having different web applications. One web site running smoothly.

Comment: Try to run one webapplication at a time.

Answer (score -3):

My workaround was to move each folder into its own folder under wwwroot.

From: 
[ASP.NET What causes: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546568/)